# Virtual method but no virtual destructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang, virtual, gnu

I see warnings like this

```
destructor called on non-final 'some_class_type' that has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
```

on gnu compilers, but on our internal continuous integration tests that also compiles with `clang`, this warning becomes an error.

Is this supposed to happen, and if so, why does clang characterize this as an error, but gnu doesn't?

Comment: Like most warnings, it's not strictly speaking an error, but it does expose you to easy mistakes. Clang is probably compiling with warnings as errors.

Comment: It's not an error by C++ standard. Probably your clang compilation has `-Werror` in compilation options.

Comment: Ah yes, after digging deeper into the compilation log, I do see that flag turned on

Comment: If in doubt whether or not a virtual destructor is needed, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Comment: Yes, put it in.  It's cheap insurance against nasty surprises, the warning is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this supposed to happen

According to standard: If the program is well-formed, then the program is supposed to be compiled successfully. The compiler is allowed to provide diagnostic messages. Lack of virtual destructor does not make the program ill-formed, even though it's a likely bug in this case.

Compilers typically have the option to treat warnings as errors. Given such option, the described behaviour is supposed to happen, even though that technically doesn't conform to the standard.

> why does clang characterize this as an error

Clang can be configured to treat warnings as errors. Given such option is enabled, that would explain this behaviour.

> but gnu doesn't?

Although GCC can also be configured to treat warnings as errors, if such option isn't enabled, that would explain this behaviour.

---

To solve the problem, declare the destructor as virtual.